# ActionController::UnknownFormat (PageController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, api, fetch-api

hope you're doing good!

I've just recently graduated from batch-882 Rio. I'm working on my portfolio and I'm face an issue. Would love if anyone could help me solve it.
I've embedded a medium Api to my Rails/React app. Done that through react and using fetch.
Although it works fine on my desktop and on Android... the page I'm doing the fetch is not working on ios.
Checking the logs on my Heroku this is what I found:

`ActionController::UnknownFormat  (PageController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.  Request.formats: ["text/css] Request.variant: [])`

Any ideas on how to fix or come around this issue?